# Android startActivityForResult from AsyncTask with context

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity, it's the **sender**. So when I push a button in this activity, it creates an `AsyncTask`, and when I get an answer from the server I have only `Context` from the **sender** activity.

Sender:
It starts `AsynTask`.

*AsyncTask (mContext is context from Sender class):*

```
Intent i = new Intent();                    
i.setClass(mContext, SecondActivity.class);
Sender act = (Sender)mContext;
act.startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

And in SecondActivity:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("result", data);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

In the Sender, I try to get **result**:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            ArrayList<MyClass> result = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("result");
            addFriends(result);
        }
    }
}
```

But the `requestCode` is equal to 0 (when I am started it with 1) and `resultCode = 0`. I don't know why.

I hope someone can help me!
Thanks!

Comment: In 2nd activity , return a result with " this.activity.getIntent(); " set any values and extras on that intent instance, then call finish on activity2.

Comment: u Mean this? 
 @Override
 public void onPause()
 {
  Intent i = new Intent();
  
  Intent data = this.getIntent();
  data.putParcelableArrayListExtra("result", addedFriends);

  i.putExtra("a",data);
  setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

  finish();
  super.onPause();
 }

Comment: Post full AsynkTask code. Try to return result to the sender NOT in the onPause method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onPause method it`s not the good place to return the result to the activity. Try to return it in the another place - on some button action or in onBackPressed method.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd activity use onBackPressed, and its works!
I dont know why dont work in onPause

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```